# Populating data from another referenced document with node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am building an application to run courses. Each course has units. Each unit has pages, questions and a quiz at the end. I thought I had everything setup correctly but if I view the list of units it only shows the id and does not populate.

Models:

```
var unitSchema = new Schema({
    number: Number,
    title:  String,
    unitCode:  String,
    pageCount: Number,
    time: Number
});
var pageSchema = new Schema({
    number: Number,
    title:  String,
    content: String,
    courseQ: Boolean,
    unitCode: String
});
var courseQuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question: String,
    choices: [],
    correct: Number
});
var quizSchema = new Schema({
    code: String,
    questions: [{
        question: String,
        choices: [],
        correct: Number
    }]
});
var courseSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    code:   String,
    state: String,
    instructor:   String,
    agency: String,
    providerNumber: String,
    schoolNumber: String,
    price: {type: Number, get: getPrice, set: setPrice },
    available: Boolean,
    units : [{ type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'unitSchema' }],
    pages : [{ type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'pageSchema' }],
    cQuestions : [{ type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'courseQuestionSchema' }],
    quizzes : [{ type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'quizSchema' }]
});
```

Schema.statics:

```
unitSchema.statics = {

    list: function (options, cb) {
        var criteria = options.criteria || {};

        this.find(criteria)
            .populate('units')
            .exec(cb)
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
exports.coursesUnits = function(req, res){
    var options = {
        criteria: { 'id':req.param('units',req.course.units.id)}
    };

    Courses.list(options, function(err, units) {
        if (err) return res.render('500');
        res.render('admin/courses/units', {
            title: '',
            description: '',
            units: req.course.units,
            course: req.course,
            active: 'courses', active2: 'course-list', active3: ''
        })
    })
};
```

I have spent all week looking for a solution to this problem with no luck. Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for you. I think you messed something up with your models. The Attribute 'ref' does only work with other models, not schemas.

You have to crate a model first using mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema)

After that you can reference to 'Quiz'.

That way it creates a new collection for the quiz and references to it using an objectId.

Here is the documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html